# ffmpeg Get time of frames from trimmed video

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg in my application to extract frames from a video, the frames will be added to a trim video view where you get an illustration as to what is happening in the video at a specific time within the video. So each frame needs to represent some time within the video.

I dont quite understand how FFmpeg is producing the frames. Here is my code:

```
"-i",
videoCroppedFile.getAbsolutePath(),
"-vf",
"fps=1/" + frameSeperation,
mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() +
"/%d.jpg"
```

My app allows you to record a video at a max length of 20s. The number of frames extracted from the video depnds on how long the captured video is. frameSeperation is calculated doing the below code.

```
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long videoLength = Long.parseLong(time) / 1000;
    double frameSeperationDouble = (double) videoLength;
    // Divide by 11 because there is a maximum of 11 frames on trim video view
    frameSeperationDouble /= 11;
    frameSeperationDouble = Math.ceil(frameSeperationDouble);
    int frameSeperation = (int) frameSeperationDouble;
```

Maybe the above logic is very bad, if there is a better way please can somebody tell me.

Anyway I run the code and below are a few test cases:

- A video captured with a length of 6 seconds has 7 frames.
- A video captured with a length of 2 seconds has 3 frames.
- A video captured with a length of 10 seconds has 12 frames.
- A video captured with a length of 15 seconds has 9 frames.
- A video captured with a length of 20 seconds has 11 frames.

There is no consistency, and I find it hard to put timestamps against each frame because of this. I feel like my logic is wrong or im not understanding. Any help is much appreciated

**Update 1**

So I did what you said in comments:

```
 final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(mContext);
        final File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/data/"
                + mContext.getPackageName()
                + "/vFrames");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(mContext, Uri.fromFile(videoCroppedFile));
    String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long videoLength = Long.parseLong(time) / 1000;
    double frameSeperationDouble = (double) videoLength / 8;

    retriever.release();

    final String cmd[] = {

            "-i",
            videoCroppedFile.getAbsolutePath(),
            "-vf",
            "fps=1/" + frameSeperationDouble,
            "-vframes," + 8,
            mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() +
            "/%d.jpg"
    };
```

I also tried `"-vframes=" + 8` at the same point where I put vFrames in cmd. It doesnt seem to work at all now no frames are being extracted from the video

Comment: if you want to get every frame of the video, just get rid of the `-vf fps=1/[frameseparation]`. If you want to capture an image every x seconds you should probably use `-r fps` instead

Answer (score 0):

This is the effective flow for `fps=x`, with the default rounding method `near`,

Generate intervals of `1/x` seconds, e,g. for `x=1/3`, intervals are 0-3s, 3-6s, 6-9s... Within each interval, pick an earlier frame whose timestamp is nearest to the midpoint of that interval. This may lead to duplicate frames, when that nearest frame belongs to an earlier interval, and was already picked for that interval. Likely to happen if source is variable frame-rate.

In your case, I would suggest to avoid rounding or stripping fractional values, if possible. Or do it at the end.

Comment: I vaguely understand what you're suggesting but not fully. Could you give me some sample code if possible? because video lengths are variable so i dont fully understand how your scenario would work. thanks

Comment: Is your goal to get 11 frames from each video, irrespective of duration?

Comment: to be honest 8 frames is the amount i want irrespective of duration

Comment: Divide the video duration by 8 and don't cast to integer. Leave (at least 2) decimal values and pass that to ffmpeg. Add `"-vframes", "8"` after the filter.

Comment: Please check updated answer. I really really appreciate your help by the way I have been stuck on this for some time.now

Comment: Can you do `double frameSeperationDouble = (double) Long.parseLong(time) / 8000;`?  "-vframes," --> comma should be outside. Add `"-vsync", + 0,`

Comment: From a syntax point of view they both dont make sense. Take a look at my screenshot https://gyazo.com/93fdf4a492d9f5ab5aa89cb17482670c

Comment: I put the `+` because you put it in the Q --> `"-vframes," + 8,`

Comment: So if I do it like you said to do it, there is a syntax error https://gyazo.com/cdd21063e194a88db9c1f3dd6b40619b any other suggestions? Is you look at the rest of my commands is there anything similar syntax? Also what is vsync supposed to do? and vFrames says how many frames to output right?

Comment: I checked online looks like vframes in String needs to be something like `-vframes 8` so thats the equivalent in my code as `"-vframes " +  8` However that produces no frames either. my full command is `final String cmd[] = {

                "-i",
                videoCroppedFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                "-vf",
                "fps=1/" + frameSeperationDouble,
                "-vframes " +  8,
                "-vsync "+ 0,
                mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                "/%d.jpg"
        };`